# Prove that $(1,1,1),(0,1,1),(0,1,-1)$ span $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

> 1. Do the vectors $(0,0,4),(0,1,3),(1,0,2)$ span $\Bbb R^3$?
> 2. Prove that $(1,1,1),(0,1,1),(0,1,-1)$ span $\Bbb R^3$

---

the first one:
$$ \left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  0&0&1&x\\
  0&1&0&y\\
  4&3&2&z
\end{array}
\right) $$
after doing gaussian elimination I got
$$ \left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  4&0&0&z-3y-2x\\
  0&1&0&y\\
  0&0&1&x
\end{array}
\right) $$

How do I continue from here?

same thing with the second part:

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&0&0&x\\
  1&1&1&y\\
  1&1&-1&z
\end{array}
\right) $$
and after gaussian elimination I got:

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&0&0&x\\
  0&1&1&y-x\\
  0&0&1&\frac{z-y}{-2}
\end{array}
\right) $$

but again how do I continue from here ? how can I show that it does span $\Bbb R^3$

thanks for any tips and help , please I am new to this I cannot use stuff I havent learned yet like proving with determinants or anything just basic operations

Comment: Hint: how many pivots are in the reduced row echelon form?

Comment: @SeanRoberson 3 pivots , the ranks of the matrices both are $3$ so there is a unique solution and it is linearly independent

Comment: Adamrk, I think you will soon be able to [type an answer to your own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @AnneBauval I am trying to type it as in $span\{...\}$ but I don't know what to put there according to the matrices that I got

Comment: You found (in each case) that your 3 vectors are linearly independent. So you won, they span a 3-dimensional subspace of the space $\Bbb R^3$, i.e. they span the whole space. Alternatively, you can transform your span step by step. E.g. for your first 3 vectors $u,v,w:$ ${\rm span}(\{u,v,w\})={\rm span}(\{u/4,v,w\})={\rm span}(\{u/4,v,w-u/4\})=\dots={\rm span}(\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}).$

Comment: Yes, see my (updated) last comment above

Comment: You must use 6 letters e.g. $a,b,c,x,y,z$.

Comment: @BobDobbs why 6? The 2 questions are independent

Comment: @BobDobbs the 2 questions are not related I forgot to mention.

Comment: @Adamrk I think You may use the same letters in both. So you don't need 12 letters.

Comment: @BobDobbs Oh! I think now I understand what you meant, but Adamrk's way of writing Gaussian elimination does not require your additional $a,b,c.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Ok. We all have  different styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $\textbf{u}=(1,1,1)$, $\textbf{v}=(0,1,1)$, and $\textbf{w}=(0,1,-1)$. Can you fill in the blanks $\ldots$ below?
\begin{aligned}
1\cdot \textbf{u}+(-1)\cdot \textbf{v}+0\cdot \textbf{w}&=\ldots\\
0\cdot \textbf{u}+0.5\cdot \textbf{v}+0.5\cdot \textbf{w}&=\ldots\\
0\cdot \textbf{u}+0.5\cdot\textbf{v}+(-0.5)\cdot\textbf{w}&=\ldots\\
\end{aligned}
(If you set out to obtain the intended RHS's above, it's pretty easy to back out the coefficients for $\textbf{u},\textbf{v}$, and $\textbf{w}$.)